# What is the most efficient way to compare rows in a MySQL table with Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

This is a largely conceptual question so i dont have any code to show. I'll try to explain this as best i can. I am writing a program that is supposed to find common sequences of numbers found in a large table of random combinations.

So for example take this data:

```
1 5 3 9 6 3 8 8 3 3

6 7 5 5 5 4 9 2 0 1

6 4 4 3 7 8 3 9 5 6 

2 4 2 4 5 5 3 4 7 7 

1 5 6 3 4 9 9 3 3 2

0 2 7 9 4 5 3 9 8 3
```

These are random combinatinos of the numbers 1-9. For every 3 digit (or more) sequence found more than once i need to put that into another database. So the first row contains "5 3 9" and the 6th row also contains "5 3 9". I would put that sequence in a separate table with the number of times it was found.

I'm still working out the algorithm for actually making these comparisons but i figure i'll have to start with "1 5 3", compare that to every single 3 number trio found, then move on to "5 3 9" then "3 9 6" etc....

MY MAIN PROBLEM RIGHT NOW is that i dont know how to do this if these numbers are stored in a database. My database table has 11 columns. One column for each individual number, and one column for the 10 digit sequence as a whole. Columns are called Sequence, 1stNum, 2ndNum, 3rdNum...10thNum.

Visual: first row in my database for the data above would be this :

```
|  1 5 3 9 6 3 8 8 3 3  |  1  |  5  |  3  |  9  |  6  |  3  |  8  |  8  |  3  |  3  |
```

("|" divide columns)

How do i make comparisons efficiently with Java? I'm iterating over every row in the table many times. Once for the initial sequence to be compared, and for every one of those sequences i go through each row. Basically a for loop in a for loop. This sounds like its going to take a ton of queries and could take forever if the table gets to be massive (which it will).

**Is it more computationally efficient if i iterate through a database using queries or if i dump the database and iterate through a file?**

I tried to explain this as best as i could, its a very confusing process for me. I can clarify anything you need me to. I just need guidance on what the best course of action for this would be.

Comment: **Why** are you doing this? Can't you read the entire contents into a List and sort it in memory?

Comment: Its part of a personal programming project i'm playing around with. The details are uber confusing, but i tried to explain by setting it up as an independent problem. I'm not sorting it at all though.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The order of the numbers is important so sorting it would defeat the purpose. If thats what you mean.

Comment: `I'm still working out the algorithm for actually making these comparisons but i figure i'll have to start with "1 5 3", compare that to every single 3 number trio found, then move on to "5 3 9" then "3 9 6" etc....` don't think it is a great idea. I would rather use a HashSet to store each encountered triplet. Each time there is a collision, I would increment the counter of this triplet in a Map<String,Integer>. This way, I think you would save a lot of time because insertion in HashSet costs less than comparing to every other triplet.

Comment: What does the act of comparing the values accomplish? Do you want a min or max of the sequences? Map it to a `Comparable` 3 field POJO?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have a database full of these sequences right? TableA. End goal is i want all the common sequences from TableA in TableB. I will not be doing any computation on the numbers. I could exchange the numbers for letters and achieve the same result.

Comment: @Dici i've never actually used a HashSet before but i will look into this. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Create a MYSQL view on TableA and skip TableB. It sounds like a trivial subset of `char(3)` *sequences*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do, assuming you have retrieved the sequences in a list :

```
List<String> sequences = Arrays.asList("1539638833","6755549201","6443783956","2424553477","1563499332","0279453983");
Map<String,Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
for (String seq : sequences) {
    int length = seq.length();
    for (int i=0 ; i<length - 2 ; i++) {
        String sub = seq.substring(i,i + 3);
        count.put(sub,count.containsKey(sub) ? count.get(sub) + 1 : 1);
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Ouput :

```
{920=1, 783=1, 945=1, 332=1, 963=1, 644=1, 156=1, 983=1, 453=1, 153=1, 388=1, 534=1,
 455=1, 245=1, 539=2, 554=1, 242=1, 555=1, 553=1, 437=1, 883=1, 349=1, 755=1, 675=1,
 638=1, 395=1, 201=1, 956=1, 933=1, 499=1, 634=1, 839=1, 794=1, 027=1, 477=1, 833=1,
 347=1, 492=1, 378=1, 279=1, 993=1, 443=1, 396=1, 398=1, 549=1, 563=1, 424=1}
```

You can then store these values in the database from the Map.

Comment: Yeah this is definitely part of it. The next issue i foresee is that, after 3 digits i have to go to 4 digits and then so on, but that seems simpler in comparison. Also though, because of the fact that these sequences are stored in my database, i suppose the best course of action would be to query it once and throw all the sequences into an initial list huh?

Comment: Also its kind of crazy that the only three common numbers found in there are "539" i was really expecting more than just one sequence found.

Comment: @RyanBrady : I also think it would be an efficient way to do it. If you want to have 4 digits, or any number of digits, this can be done with minor changes in the code. Finally, there are a total of 1000 possible combinations and you have only 48 in your example, so the probability of not having duplicates is quite high.

Comment: You have no idea how excited i am to use this :) I didnt think it would be 11 lines of code haha. I'm going to play around with it, but i may come back and ask questions. Thanks a ton. I'll come back and checkmark this answer if it works as intended.

Comment: @RyanBrady : Haha, make the Java Collection API your friend to become efficient. `HashSet` and `HashMap` are really useful. You should read their doc as well as `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `TreeSet`. Then, depending on your needs, there are some other interesting classes such `ArrayDeque`, `PriorityQueue`...

Comment: I love my ArrayLists and HashMaps. Im making a point to learn the other ones on there as well though. Starting with HashSet. I'm running into trouble now because my actual data isnt digits 1-9. Its literally any number. So my first set could be (4 392 74 4 8933 34 48 234556 43 88). There are spaces between the numbers. But because of this it makes certain lines wrong. I changed int length to be equal to seq.split("\\s").length but i'm not sure about the rest

Comment: @RyanBrady : wouldn't `seq.replace("\\s","")` be better ? Plus, I realize that the HashSet is not necessary here, a simple HashMap would do =. I am going to add this other solution (almost the same though, but probably better in terms of memory).

Comment: well that would just make one super long number. I need to keep 4 separate from 392. I wont be breaking up 392 to use its own digits for comparison, but rather i compare right to 392. If that makes sense. So i split seq into a word array and changed sub to String sub = (wordArray[i] + " " + wordArray[i+1] + " " + wordArray[i+2]);

Comment: The next problem i think that i'm going to run into though is that not all my number sets are numbers long. It varies between 3 and 17. But thats something i'll look into i've already used you enough :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61188/discussion-between-dici-and-ryan-brady).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in sql with a union clause:

```
select sum(c), sequence 
from
(   
    select
        count(*) as c, concat(col1 ,col2 , col3) as sequence
        from t
        group by col1, col2, col3
    union
    select
        count(*) as c, concat(col2 ,col3 , col4) as sequence
        from t
        group by col2, col3, col4
    union (... and so on enumerating through the column combinations)
) as tt
group by sequence
```

I would imagine a pure java implementation would be quicker and have less
memory overhead. But if you already have it in the database it may be quick
enough.

Comment: Holy cow. I'm not so good at constructing SQL queries, but i never even considered it would be possible to do that way. When you say "col1", "col2" etc. Those columns are supposed to hold the individual digits right? You do nothing with the column that contains the entire 10 digit sequence?

Comment: col1 would be '1stNum' for your table. Adding in the 10 sequence column would fry your results because the groupings would all be unique, unless the 10 digit number repeats. The group by clause can only have the columns you are 'grouping by'.

Comment: Sql really does not like to have it its records be treated as arrays. That is why it would be a very verbose query as you can't easily index rows like you can in a procedural language. If you want to try every combination it would be a little tedious to type but definitely doable.